# JAVA reuse onTouchListener, setOnFocusChangeListener Events for editText

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
    dateField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {               
            if(!hasFocus && TextUtils.isEmpty(dateField.getText().toString())){
                dateField.setText(DateDefaultValue);
            }  else if (hasFocus && dateField.getText().toString().equals(DateDefaultValue)){
                dateField.setText("");                  
            }
            else
            {btnShowHide.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);}
             if (!hasFocus)
            {
                if (dateField.getText().length() >0)

                    btnShowHide.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
            }         
        }
    });
```

I want to reuse my event for setOnFocusChangeListener and onTouchListener and for all of my events for my editText Fields without doing copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an anonymous inner method you should create a new class ( e.g. MyListener() ).

```
class MyListener extends FocusChangeListener{
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus && TextUtils.isEmpty(dateField.getText().toString())){
        dateField.setText(DateDefaultValue);
} else if (hasFocus&&dateField.getText().toString().equals(DateDefaultValue)){
        dateField.setText("");
}else{
        btnShowHide.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);}
        if (!hasFocus && dateField.getText().length() >0)
        {
        btnShowHide.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
        }
}
}
```

and use it like this: `dateField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new MyListener());`

Also I'm not familiar with the Android API but if it doesn't work try replacing `extends` with `implements`

Comment: I have many editText fields, i need to reuse those events to make my code neat and simple by not using editText1, editText2... i want to assign it to an one variable editTextEvent to easily reuse my events.

Comment: That's what I told you to do? for each object you need a listener for, simply use Field1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new MyListener()); -- Also, just noticed an error in my reply. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You should create only one listener and reference all view event to this like

```
   private FocusChangeListener mFocusChangeListener = new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {   
            if(v == dateField){....} 
            else if(v == nameField){....}

            if(!hasFocus && TextUtils.isEmpty(dateField.getText().toString())){
                dateField.setText(DateDefaultValue);
            }  else if (hasFocus && dateField.getText().toString().equals(DateDefaultValue)){
                dateField.setText("");                  
            }
            else
            {btnShowHide.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);}
             if (!hasFocus)
            {
                if (dateField.getText().length() >0)

                    btnShowHide.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
            }         
        }
    }
```

and then:

```
dateField.setOnFocusChangeListener(mFocusChangeListener);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: isn't this going to result in wrong invocation of its callback?